# Bind DNS on Linux Box not resolving some subdomains from users.storage.live.com

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain, bind

I have 2 BIND servers and they work fine, but when I try to upload some files through skydrive  the page tells me that an error occured, if i change my dns info in my nic to public dns server they work fine, also it works fine with another of my dns servers that is a Windows 2008 DNS server.

3 Servers (2 bind, 1 windows) are in the same firewall zone, same rules apply, all the other domains are resolved fine as far as I can tell, except these ones in the form of caadfdbdf34134.users.storage.live.com

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use dnstrace to debug the issue.

That may help with more information.